# Is it legal to use attribute on init-statement in a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, ranged-loops, c++-attributes

Example:

```cpp
std::array arr{1,2,3,4,5};
for([[maybe_unused]] int a = -10; auto i : arr)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    std::cout << i + a;
}
```

This seems to work fine on GCC and Clang, but fails to compile with MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/reP5vPM6h with the error:

```
error C2059: syntax error: ':'
error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '{'
error C3536: 'i': cannot be used before it is initialized
```

---

But for some reason this compiles fine on MSVC, despite I don't think it's legal:

```
for(int [[maybe_unused]] a = -10; auto i : arr) {}
```

Link: https://godbolt.org/z/snv7Tqahh

Comment: `for(int a [[maybe_unused]] = -10; auto i : arr)` works for [all](https://godbolt.org/z/K4dM7eE4d) compilers.

Comment: @康桓瑋 Didn't know that was a valid syntax (or is it?)

Comment: It is perfectly valid syntax. As applied to the [function](https://godbolt.org/z/4GYdMhaEh): `void f [[maybe_unused]] () { }`

Comment: @康桓瑋 make that an answer?